# Installing Orange Package with older Python Version?

Tags: python, orange, pip

I am trying to install an Add-on package from GitHub that contains prototype widgets for Orange Data Mining. I am trying to install it from the GitHub page found [here](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-prototypes.git).

I am using the following Terminal code to install this:

```
git clone http://github.com/biolab/orange3-prototypes.git
```

Everything then appears to install correctly and the download shows 100%. Then, however, it throws an error and says:

> Orange requires Python >= 3.4

I am using Mac OS. Clearly, it is suggesting that I need to use a different version of python to install, however, I already updated my pip install. Any insight into how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message shows exactly what you need to do:

> Orange requires Python>=3.4

You have to specify a Python>=3.4 version (with orange3 itself installed) while installing `orange3-prototypes`.

I'm not a Mac user, however, in Windows, Orange3 installer will automatically install a Python 3.4 if there's no compatible Python available.

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip`.